# How to setblock a command block with a /summon command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a one command creation, so I need a `/setblock` command to set a command block with a `/summon` command. This is the command I'm using:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:command_block 4 replace {auto:0b,powered:0b,conditionMet:0b,Command:"/execute @e[type=Wolf,name=MiniMe] ~ ~ ~ /summon Wolf ~ ~ ~ {Owner:PLAYER_NAME,CustomName:"Mini"}",TrackOutput:0}
```

It keeps saying:

```
"Data tag parsing failed: Unexpected token 'M' at: Mini"}",TrackOutput:0"
```

When I use the `/summon` command normally it works fine! Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The first quotation mark you use opens the string, and thus the very next un-escaped quotation mark will close it, which happens for your `CustomName` value. In order to avoid using a quotation mark to close the string, you must escape it by prepending it with a backslash (`\"`).

If you need to use more quotation marks as part of the value at a deeper nesting within quotation marks, you'd need to apply more backslashes. The equation for the number of backslashes is `2n+1` where `n` is the current number of backslashes. For example, if you need quotation marks within an already-escaped set of quotation marks that have 1 backslash, you would need `2*1+1` backslashes (3).

Fixed command applying the backslash:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:command_block 4 replace {auto:0b,powered:0b,conditionMet:0b,Command:"/execute @e[type=Wolf,name=MiniMe] ~ ~ ~ /summon Wolf ~ ~ ~ {Owner:PLAYER_NAME,CustomName:\"Mini\"}",TrackOutput:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are basically closing the command that would go into the command block with the `"` preceding `Mini`. Since you don't have any spaces in the custom name you can do this:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:command_block 4 replace {auto:0b,powered:0b,conditionMet:0b,Command:"/execute @e[type=Wolf,name=MiniMe] ~ ~ ~ /summon Wolf ~ ~ ~ {Owner:PLAYER_NAME,CustomName:Mini}",TrackOutput:0}
```

Comment: "Since you don't have any spaces in the custom name you can do this" This implies that you need quotation marks if you have spaces, which is not the case. The main purpose of quotation marks as far as the parser is concerned is to allow commas as the value. Its secondary purpose is to ensure that the tag cannot be parsed as any other type, as strings are only used when no other type could match. It would be good practice to use quotation marks for strings for that purpose.